# Something (Tomcat?) replaces my Rest repsonse

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a trivial spring-boot web-app communicating using json, that is working perfectly.

Then I decided to clean up the error handling (after reading [this](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)) by introducing a global @ControllerAdvice annotated class with a few exception handler methods (which are called correctly) but somewhere the response is converted to a Tomcat standard fault instead of the RestErrorInfo I want.

The code that I added for global error handling:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public RestErrorInfo handleSpringDataConflict() {
        return new RestErrorInfo(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, "database problem");
    }
    ...
}
```

I expected to get a 409 with a RestErrorInfo in the body but the response I get:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/rest/books 405 (Method Not Allowed) :8080/rest/books:1
HTTP 405: <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Request method 'POST' not supported</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.52</h3></body></html>
```

If I post something that is allowed the app works fine returning with a 200 (will soon change to 201;-) and the Rest object.

And I am using:
 spring 4.0.3.RELEASE
 spring-boot 1.0.1.RELEASE
 spring-security 3.2.1.RELEASE

And another thing that might mess it up: I use a Filter to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin in headers.

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public static final List<String> ALL_METHODS = Arrays.asList("OPTIONS", "GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "TRACE", "CONNECT");

    public void doFilter(@NotNull final ServletRequest req, @NotNull final ServletResponse res, @NotNull final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", String.join(", ", ALL_METHODS));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Content-Type, accept");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
    public void init(@NotNull final FilterConfig filterConfig) {}
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting the response to be a json response?

Comment: yes I was hoping for json (application/json) as I get on a successful call. And specifically the RestErrorInfo object as json.

Comment: Check my answer. It is the same as your code but with a `@ResponseBody` annotation (as is used in the tutorial you included)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the code to the following:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
@ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
@ResponseBody
public RestErrorInfo handleSpringDataConflict() {
     return new RestErrorInfo(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, "database problem");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had been sitting with this for a few hours and the problem is that I can't even copy/paste correctly :-)